# Henry Adams’s use of punctuation, “:—”

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation

I’ve never seen the construction before, except in Spanish for dialogue and Toni Morrison using the variation “;—” in *Beloved* for denoting a strong pause (well, that’s what we decided in my English class).

How does Henry Adams use “:—”? Is this grammatically correct? How can I incorporate this into my own sentences?

> Among senses, smell was the strongest:—the smell of hot pine-woods and sweet-fern in the scorching summer noon; of new-mown hay; of ploughed earth 
> — Henry Adams, in *The Education of Henry Adams*

Comment: It's also used at the end of the preamble in UK Acts of Parliament, e.g.: http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/30/introduction

Comment: As I write, there's a pending edit suggesting OP's citation should be changed to *...was the strongest **:—** the smell of hot...* But searching for [that **exact** text in Google Books](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22and+sweet-fern+in+the+scorching+summer+noon%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), only one out of several dozen has a colon before the em-dash. None have a semicolon, which is equally nonsensical. I therefore think this question is Off Topic because it's just asking about a mistranscription/typo.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Answer (score 3):

Taking a break from typing court orders, and specifically

> The Court has sent sealed copies of this Order to: -
>
> Smith & Jones
>
> Brown & Robinson
>
> and the Court of Appeal

I can say that it is used in formal contexts as a strengthened colon: that is, either at the beginning of a list (as in my example), or before an expansion of what has just been said, as in Steve Melnikoff's example.  I imagine it is a shortening of *viz:-* and was later abbreviated to a simple colon.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen that used before. Reading your example sentence, I treat it just like a regular —. You can probably do whatever you want in your own books, but I would just use —.