# What is ":-" used for?

Tags: punctuation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Henry Adam’s use of punctuation, “:—”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4316/henry-adams-use-of-punctuation)

I've seen a couple of times, ":-" occurring where I could expect just a colon to occur, perhaps preceding a list.

When is it correct to use ":-"?

What is it called?

Am I simply wrong and think I remember seeing this, when in actual fact I didn't?

Comment: Until I read @StoneyB's answer, I wondered if it was an emoticon depicting [someone with no mouth](http://allthingslearning.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/no-mouth.jpg?w=604).

Comment: On a side note, ":-" is used in Swedish (and probably elsewhere – at least in German, I think, but punctuation is hard to search for…) for an amount of money. "123:-" is 123 SEK. The ":-" stands for "and no cents", cf. "123:45" for 123 SEK and 45 cents ("öre").

Comment: I use Grammarly. It is Okay when it corrects :- (colon hyphen) to : (simple colon) seeing that it is a punctuation error; But when it suggests to change it into -: (hyphen colon), and I see it everywhere now a days, I don't know why it does that. [When I was more than 7 years old, I used colon hyphen followed by bulleted list from the next line].

Answer (score 10):

This is an old usage, now obsolete. Graves and Hodge (*The Reader Over Your Shoulder*, 1943) describe it thus:

> A long dash may be put after a colon, for emphasis. For example:
>
> > > ‘The Captain arose and said: “Come, Antonio, amuse the men, and tell them one of your favourite stories!” Antonio arose, rolled the quid from side to side in his coarse mouth and, after a pause, began thus:—
> > >         “About  the year 1874, in Lisbon . . . ”’

Note that the colon-dash construction is distinct from the internal colon.

*OED 1* employs  :— in etymologies to signify an “extant representative, or regular phonetic descendant of”. According to tchrist, *OED 2* and *OED 3* employ it similarly to signify “normal development of”.

Comment: Might I please trouble you to incorporate the OED use of this digraph into your answer? If it's too much trouble, may I do so for you, please? FYI in my print version of the OED2, it is a em dash, but I think that is what your example above is, also. From the dead: tchrist In the "List of Abbreviations, Signs, &c" it is said that "in the Etymol. [...] :— = extant representative, or regular phonetic descendant of" – StoneyB 5 hours ago. StoneyB Thanks. I didn’t even think to look there. In the OED2, it defines it as “normal development of”, which I never realized. – tchrist 5 hours ago.

Comment: @tchrist There you go. If you can figure out how to pretty up the blockquote, please do; in RoYS the blockquote and individual paragraphs are both indented.

Comment: This reminds me of the double dash (which I'll mimic with an equals sign) found, to my knowledge, only in the Waldorf=Astoria (Hotel).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  –  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hyphen) says this double hyphen is a glyphic variant (usually oblique) in Fraktur faces; is employed in some dictionaries to disambiguate line-end hyphenation when this coincides with the hyphen in a compound; and is a distinct point in Coptic, Ojibwe, and Japanese katakana.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You mean the double-hyphen, not the double-dash: hyphens join, while dashes separate. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hyphen).  I am especially fond of using the double-hyphen to show a literal hyphen that occurs at a linebreak, as was done in certain dictionaries of old. But then, I like my hyphens hung in the margin, too, which is distressingly rare these days. It's like we've forgotten everything Gutenberg ever taught us.

Comment: @tchrist  And hanging and running quotes? But the real test: do you hang the first letter of lines of poetry, like OF Mss?

Comment: Dash is used to specify ranges : 1 - 10, while hyphen is used when there are related words : son-in-law. Both look same but their usage is different.